# How do I get to this query? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I have a database schema :

```
member(memb_no, name, age)  
book(isbn, title, authors, publisher)  
borrowed(memb_no, isbn, date)
```

This is the question:

> For each publisher, print the names of members who have borrowed more than ﬁve 
>   books of that publisher.

How do I write query for this?

Below is my attempt:

```
Select B.publisher,
M.memb_no, M.name  
From book as B,
member as M,
borrowed as R  
Where M.memb_no = R.memb_no and B.isbn = R.isbn and R.isbn in   
(select B.publisher, count (R.isbn)   
from borrowed as R and book as B   
where B.isbn = R.isbn   
group by B.publisher   
having count >5);
```

Please point out the errors and explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
WITH  publisher_memb_cte (publisher,memb_no)
AS
(
SELECT b.publisher,r.memb_no
FROM book b
JOIN borrowed r ON b.isbn=r.isbn
group by b.publisher,r.memb_no
HAVING count (*)>5
)
SELECT cte.publisher, m.name
FROM publisher_memb_cte cte
JOIN member m on cte.memb_no = m.memb_no
```

Tips to avoid performance penalties:

1. avoid if possible selects in the where clause
2. use joins instead of "joining" in the where clause

The syntax error in your code is at:

```
from borrowed as R and book as B
```

which should be

```
from borrowed as R, book as B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    with book_borrowed(memb_no , isbn , publisher) as

    (  select memb_no , borrowed.isbn , publisher

       from

       book join borrowed on book.isbn = borrowed.isbn
    ) 


    select  name , publisher

    from book_borrowed join member on book_borrowed.memb_no = member.memb_no

    group by member.memb_no , publisher , name

    having count(isbn) > 5;
```